Comic book identification - investigative journalist, 1980s, aliens pretending to be human
I've been looking for a graphic novel for ages now, tried different subreddits, Facebook groups, picked the brain of family and friends, sadly to no avail...
It was a hand me down graphic novel, my introduction to the genre as a child. My siblings don't even recall this graphic novel.
The main character is an investigative journalist who is working on an assignment (undercover as an architect?) I can only recall the following info: He's got blond hair, glasses, and khaki trousers/or a shirt. It's his first time in this city. He accidentally witnesses an illegal operation involving a yellow blow-up rescue boat (smuggling?). The family he tries to get info on seems to be very dismissive, and they close ranks very early on, however he manages to chat with one of the adult daughters.
As he falls for the woman, it turns out the family's secret is that they're aliens from a far far away planet. This info is revealed on the very last page, she is wearing a blue body suit (long romper) at this point.
